# Uninstall Build Agent from Teamcity (Windows)

Tags: teamcity

I have been researching but can't seem to find anything on uninstalling a build agent from Teamcity. I have read that if I can stop the service there should be a '**Remove**' button that appears under that agencies summary section.  I have tried stopping the service through Server Manager, as well as, running the `service.stop.bat` under the `<agent>\bin`, but have had no success with the button appearing. Is there an easy way to remove the build agent from Teamcity?

Current Teamcity version: `TeamCity Professional 10.0.3`

Comment: Sounds a bit.. Wrong, but you can just uninstall the whole lot and reinstall it all, teamcity wont destroy any data to do with your teamcity setup in the uninstall process. Its a right pain that it isnt a separate install in the add remove programs list though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked buildAgent/bin folder? There should be **uninstall.bat** file, which, I assume, should do just what you want.

Comment: I had to run the bat file through the command prompt, but was able to use the `uninstall.bat` with this command `uninstall.bat <path_to_agent_folder>`. This cleaned up everything related to that build agent.  Thanks @grundic